VS Code and Perl under WSL
I am trying to get VSCode working with Perl on my W11 machine using WSL2. VSCode is installed and running. I finally got Perl::LanguageServer installed. When I open a perl script in VSCode it does not recognize it as executable, i.e. there is no run icon at the top right of the window like there is for python.
Added at the request of whomever closed this...The desired behavior of for VS Code to debug a Perl script like this:
use feature ":5.10";
my $foo = "This is a test.";
say foo;

There are no error messages, it just fails to run/debug the script.
I put the following in the JSON config file.
 {
  "perl": {
    "perlCmd": "/usr/bin/perl",
    "perlInc": [],
    "enable": true,
    "lintCmd": "perl -c",
    "includePaths": [],
    "fileExtensions": [".pl", ".pm", ".t"],
    "ignoreDirs": [".vscode", "node_modules"],
    "logLevel": 2,
    "showDocPath": true
  },
  "perl-toolbox.perl-path": "/usr/bin/perl",
  "perlcritic.enable": true
}

Can someone point me in the right direction?

See also: https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/15800c09d36ba8ee034ca1b962ad33e2

perl -c does a testrun of a program and reports errors.

@Håkon I had Richter's extension installed already, so when it said I didn't have an extension I did. Now, when I try to set a breakpoint, VSCode won't let me. perl -c test.pl runs fince.

So...it gave me some message about installing the extension in a different location. I clicked that, it opened a tab, and now I can set breakpoints. I click run and debug, the progress bar appears above that, it runs for a while then goes away, and doesn't stop at the breakpoint or produce any output.

Try to uninstall VS Code and then reinstall. Then install the Perl Language server extension again.

I uninstalled VC Code and reinstalled. When I opened it, Perl Language Server was there already.

What happens if you uninstall Perl Language Server, and then reinstall it?

That seemed to do it. Thanks for the come-backs.
